# Are there any alternative ways to install Ubuntu other than CD and USB? (Without WUBI)

Tags: 14.04, usb, wubi, cd

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on my Windows 7 computer. But my only USB stick is currently at school and I am on holiday break until next week. I can't use a DVD because I don't have one and the only disks i have are 700MB CD disks which the Ubuntu ISO will not fit on it. I'd rather not use Wubi because I want a seperate partition and Wubi is generating errors on my computer so i cant use that either. SO are there any alternative ways?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Use the server image, and select `ubuntu-desktop` at the software selection stage.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the minimal installation ISO instead. They are about 36MB.

The installation will then download files as needed during installation.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: The Ubuntu mini.iso file works well in BIOS mode, and you can use the Ubuntu Server iso file to install both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode. Both iso files fit within the CD size limit.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use vm virtual box first download it. type new than ubuntu in it  click ok . after that click setting in it click storage select empty press ok. then click start. your ubuntu will open in windows without any disturbance.